# Android Virtual Device (AVD) can't run in Android Studio | HAXM can't be installed properly

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualization, hardware-acceleration, android-virtual-device

Installing android virtual device (AVD) with Intel HAXM support

Installing HAXM via android studio sdk manager gives no error.. but in AVD Manager, an error displayed - "/dev/kvm is not found" and hence doesn't allow me to run AVD

Installing HAXM(6.1.2) by downloading from intel official website gives me an error "Failed to configure driver: unknown error. Failed to open driver" which I tried to resolve using this solution given on intel blog :
https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/04/25/workaround-patch-for-haxm-installation-error-failed-to-configure-driver-unknown
But still this is not working for me as comments shows for few people it is not working too..

Now, Clicking on green run button gives me same error in addition it displays something more related to "enable Intel VT-x from bios"
Now, in my computer's bios settings.. there is no VT-x but just "Intel VT" feature that I enabled.. but still no difference.. same error message.. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling android studio and AVD.. still no solution

My PC config is :
4gb ram ddr3
Intel i3 550 3.20 ghz
BIOS version TCIBX10H.86A.0037 (not updated - latest firmware is TCIBX10H.86A.0048)
Intel hd graphics
500gb hdd
Windows 7 32bit

PS:
1. Hyper-v is not installed on my computer (may be not supported or Windows need to be installed, I never tried to install it myself)
2. There is no virtual box installed either
3. Sorry for bad english and I'm new to android development also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer doesn't support haxm you can use another android emulator to run or debug your applications i use genymotion its work fine for me and its how to use genymotion to run android studio applications [here](http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2013/11/22/android-studio-plus-genymotion-emulator/)

Comment: Installing genymotion (or any other 3rd party emulator) will be our last option as it voids our company's privacy policies. I have another PC of my colleague, but I don't know exact configuration of it. Still I came to know that it has 64-bit Windows 7 installed and some high end Nvedia graphics card installed. I'll try using it and let you know.

Comment: I could never found why the error continued even if I got VT - x supported and enabled on both the PCs now.. (I checked using 'Intel® Processor Identification Utility' and 'securable.exe') finally i had to move on to 3rd party emulators whic run on VirtualBox (like Genymotion) as suggested.